# SQL SHELL. client_encoding not displaying properly 'UTF8' or 'WIN1252'

Tags: windows, postgresql, character-encoding, psql

When I use 'UTF8' it's weird characters

```
postgres=# set client_encoding to 'UTF8';

postgres=# insert into workingon(2,1,150);

DzD"D~D`DsD?:  D_Ñ^D,D±DºD° Ñ?D,D½Ñ,D°DºÑ?D,Ñ?D° (D¿Ñ?D,D¼DµÑ?D½D_Dµ D¿D_D»D_DDµD½D,Dµ: "2")
LINE 1: insert into workingon(2,1,150);
```

When I use 'WIN1252' it's not working

```
postgres=# set client_encoding to 'WIN1252';

SET

postgres=# insert into workingon(2,1,150);

ERROR:  character with byte sequence 0xd0 0x9e in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "WIN1252"
```

Comment: I don't know what's wrong, Im using SQL Shell on Windows 10, and when I switch encodings UTF8 and WIN1252 neither of them are working

Comment: What shell do you refer to? Or rather, what terminal? The fist text is the result of displaying UTF8 (ie multibyte) text as ASCII. This has nothing to do with *PostgreSQL*, it's a problem with the terminal or the OS settings. If you're on Linux, what are your LC_ settings?

Comment: I am on Windows 10, and using sql shell comand line(psql)

Comment: But what *terminal*? The old Console? Windows Terminal? WT works with UTF8 out of the box. The old console is a bit of a mess - you may have to run `chcp 65001` to switch the codepage to UTF8 and/or enable UTF8 in the Properties (for older Win10) versions

Comment: SQL Shell (psql) Windows 10 latest version.
I don't know what is terminal. I installed sql from https://www.postgresql.org/ and after installation I type sql in search bar in windows and there's a sql shell (psql) in options, I open that and it's a window with black background where I can type code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting `lc_messages = C` so that error messages are displayed in a language that can be encoded in `WIN1252`.

You best change the setting in `postgresql.conf` and reload. This setting will also affect the language of the log file, and if you ever want to search the web for an error message, English is the best choice.

Comment: how do I do that?
I tried:

[   postgres=# set lc_messages = C;   ]

and it tried to do my commands again:

[   postgres=# set lc_messages = C; ]

[   SET   ]

[   postgres=# insert into workingon(2,1,150);   ]
[   ERROR:  character with byte sequence 0xd   
0 0x9e in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "WIN1252"]

                              ^

Comment: omg sorry I don't know how to make a new line im comments

Comment: [   postgres=# set client_encoding to 'UTF8';   ]
[   SET   ]
[   postgres=# insert into workingon(2,1,150);   ]
[   DzD"D~D`DsD?:  D_Ñ^D,D±DºD° Ñ?D,D½Ñ,D°DºÑ?D,Ñ?D° (D¿Ñ?D,D¼DµÑ?D½D_Dµ D¿D_D»D_DDµD½D,Dµ: "2")   ]
[   LINE 1: insert into workingon(2,1,150); ']

Comment: Sorry for being too terse, I have expanded the answer.